# Android - how to add progress bar after the last item of Horizontal Listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have a Horizontal listview display a list of product. This list is gotten from server.

I want to load 10 items first. When user scroll to the last item of listview, the progress bar stay in here then I will load the next 10 items and so on.

With the ListView (Vertical), we have the attribute: horizontalSpacing to padding at the last item, but in Horizontal Listview I can not find any similar attribute or function.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You could override `getCount()` in your adapter and return your list `size + 1` and in `getView()` , check if the position is the last one, and render the ProgressBar (as you get the next 10 items simultaneously)

Comment: please consider accepting an answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Android documentation for [swipe-to-refresh](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html)

Answer (score 0):

you should use recyclerview instead of listview, then you can customize each row in your list based on position